# standard ml sorting 3 elements

Tags: list, sorting, standards, sml, ml

I'm trying to make a standard ml function which takes 3 elements as input and returns a  sorted list which is sorted from smallest to largest. I used 3 helper methods that gets me the min, max and the mid elements. the codes are below:

```
- fun min3 (a, b, c):real = 
    if a < b andalso a < c then a
        else if b < a andalso b < c then b
        else c;

- fun mid3 (a, b, c):real = 
    if (a < b andalso a > c) orelse (a > b andalso a < c) then a
        else if (b < a andalso b > c) orelse (b > a andalso b < c) then b
        else c;

- fun max3 (a, b, c):real = 
    if a > b andalso a > c then a
    else if b > a andalso b > c then b
        else c;

- fun sort3 (a, b, c):real = 
    min3(a, b, c)::mid3(a, b, c)::max3(a, b, c)::[];
```

the following worked perfectly when dealing with ints, but when i changed them to reals, the helper methods returned the correct results but i get error when typing the sort method which is the following (couldnt copy the error text so i took a screen shot) :

[image]

what could be wrong in the code?
Thanks

Also, is there another way of sorting 3 elements other than the way i posted here or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing the types, you've made a mistake with the return value of `sort3`. The error message is telling you that you declared `sort3` to return a real while in fact it returns a list of reals.

Comment: what if i made each element return by the helper methods a list itself and concatenated them by the @ operator, will it then know the return as a list?

Comment: @aizen92 It already knows it returns a list. The problem is that you explicitly said it should return a real when you wrote `fun sort3 (a, b, c):real`

Comment: but i want it to return real, i want to make this method work on real only

Comment: if i remove the :real part from the header of sort method, will it still consider them as real if i used the helper methods in them, since the helper methods need reals?

Comment: I tried it with removing the :real part from the sort header and it worked

Comment: @aizen92 No, you don't want it to return a real, you want it to return a **real list**. If you remove the type annotation, it will be inferred correctly. But you can also just change it to say that you're returning a list of reals, rather than a single real.

Comment: but isnt the ":real" for the type of the parameters?

Comment: @aizen92 No, it's for the type of the result. The type of the parameters goes after each parameter, i.e. `fun sort3 (a:real, b:real, c:real) : real list`.

Comment: ohhh, i see
Thanks for the help sepp2k